# Undefined variable: contents in ZipArchive.php line 173

Tags: php, laravel-5

I wanted to import xls file in laravel and export the data in database.
But I am getting following error while importing

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined variable: contents', 'C:\Users\Kuldeeo\Downloads\app\vendor\phpoffice\phpexcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\ZipArchive.php', 174, array('fileName' => '_rels/.rels', 'list' => 0, 'listCount' => 1, 'list_index' => -1, 'i' => 1, 'extracted' => 0, 'filename' => 'rels/.rels'))

I have tried adding

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::PCLZIP);
```

in Reader/Excel2007.php and Writer/Excel2007.php

even updated the composer several times. Downloading the xls file is working but importing it, is producing the error.
Kindly help.....

Answer (score 0):

I am using package = `"maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1"` in laravel to import xls file and store in DB like this I hope it helps you.

```
Route::get('/route_name', function () {
   \Excel::load("file_path/file_name.xls", function($reader) {
        $sheetTitle = array();
        $results = $reader->all();
        foreach($results as $key=>$sheet)
        {
            $sheetTitle[$key]["id"] = (int)$sheet->id;
            $sheetTitle[$key]["plan_id"] = (int)$sheet->plan_id;
            $sheetTitle[$key]["description"] = $sheet->description;
        }
        \DB::table('table_name')->insert($sheetTitle);
        return dd(\DB::table('table_name')->get());
    });
});
```

`id`,`plan_id`,`description` are title (first row) of excel file.

Update

Or may be you can use in controller as

```
Route::post('/route_name', 'UserController@importData');
```

And in `UserController`

```
function importData(Request $request){
     \Excel::load($request->file('excel_file'), function($reader) {
     .....//All code will be same as above.
}
```

Comment: The problem which I was facing was with respect to path. $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath(); This path was unable to load in the Excel:load() method. I replaced it with the static path and then it started working but still i need to pass the data from client using Input type file. Let me know if any input

Comment: @KuldeepDubey you can send file from user form and then get by `$request->file('excel_file')` and pass it to load function. Don't forget to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag

Comment: I did the same thing. <form style="border: 4px solid #a1a1a1;margin-top: 15px;padding: 10px;" action="{{ URL::to('importExcel') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   {{csrf_field()}}
   <input type="file" name="import_file" />
   </br>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Import File</button>
  </form>    And in server:  $path = Input::file('import_file')->getPathName();

Comment: the path I m getting is C:\wamp64\tmp\php4E96.tmp which is unable to open